# My jsfiddle for replacing url is working but not in blogger source

Tags: javascript, jquery, scripting

This question is specific to blogger, JSfiddle is working fine

I have a jsfiddle , where I can replace url for YouTube.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaisonshereen/q3rmyjvd/14/

jsfiddle when you run you can see its replacing url and showing the replaced video.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Mmlc3gJeBUo" frameborder="0" width="640" height="480" ></iframe>
document.getElementById('ytplayer').src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/EDk3YnVpQes";
```

But when I put this code in blogger source mode, urls are not replaced

I want to convert this YouTube video

http://www.youtube.com/embed/Mmlc3gJeBUo

with this YouTube video

http://www.youtube.com/embed/EDk3YnVpQes

This is the blogger post source code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById('ytplayer').src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/EDk3YnVpQes";
  </script>

<iframe id="ytplayer" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/pXquZBc8td0" frameborder="0" width="640" height="480" ></iframe>
```

Here is the blog : https://blogs.giftyourhubby.com/2021/08/test.html

Comment: iframe doesn't exist when that script runs. Look at error thrown in dev tools console: `document.getElementById('ytplayer') is null`

Comment: please don't close this , this is a different question

Comment: @charlietfl plase help me why this is null

Comment: Not different at all. Move the script tag or use a load event to run the js. Did you try either? Do you see the error thrown in dev tools console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Comment: where should i move the script tag?

Comment: Read the well documented explanation of the problem in the duplicate link. The solutions are also well written

Comment: window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('ytplayer').src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/EDk3YnVpQes";
 }; Not workng

Comment: script tag a moved in body tag still not working

Comment: Any errors? Look in console

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Probably not related to code shown

Comment: <body>
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(function() {
   document.getElementById('ytplayer').src = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/EDk3YnVpQes";
});
   </script>
  <iframe id="ytplayer" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Mmlc3gJeBUo" frameborder="0" width="640" height="480" ></iframe>
</body>

Comment: https://blogs.giftyourhubby.com/2021/08/test.html

Comment: see the source of this link to see the code

Comment: Note the `http` version of youtube is blocked, need `https`. Also see other errors you need to resolve. Loading scripts from http will also be blocked since page is on https

Comment: I updated with https , it worked, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Was all there in console messages

Comment: :) glad it worked and more than that for your help